# Why can't I find dominator on mage class on rift?

Tags: rift

I downloaded the game rift yesterday and it shows you can make your mage a dominator but there is no dominator option on my soul trees? Did that content get removed or something?

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely looking at the presets. Dominator is still free and still available, but you need to close the presets in order to choose three custom souls, one of which will be Dominator.